# Will having two versions of mscomctl.ocx referenced in an application cause problems?

Tags: vb6, activex, windows-server-2012

I maintain a lot of old VB6 code. The programs have been around a long time and run on many systems with no problems.

Recently we have been having strange, random problems with these programs on Server 2012.

I noticed that the project file referenced mscomctl.ocx#2.0 and a form file in the project referenced mscomctl.ocx#2.1.

Project file (vbp)
Object={831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.0#0; MSCOMCTL.OCX

Form file (frm)
Object={831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.1#0; MSCOMCTL.OCX

A process dump showed comctl32.dll was loaded twice

LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9200.17359_none_bf105a8645f47e85\COMCTL32.dll
...
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9200.17359_none_8935f06086091acc\comctl32.DLL

From what I could Google, it seems that comctl32.dll is a dependency of MSCOMCTL.OCX, which is also loaded.

LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mscomctl.ocx

Is this cause for alarm?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: PS: I plan on changing them all to version 0 but that will be a huge task (lots of programs) so it would be nice to know if I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Your project (.VBP file) probably lacks the proper setting for *Upgrade ActiveX Controls*.

Open that file in a text editor and remove any line:

```
NoControlUpgrade=1
```

Or open the project in VB6 and check the box in the Project Properties dialog.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I found that AFTER the damage was done but I will make sure all developers set that setting. I am still going through the hundreds of programs and resetting the versions and don't want to do it again.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES!

After I went through hundreds of programs and set them all to version 2.0 for MSCOMCTL.OCX and recompiled them, the problem stopped (Server 2012 caches applications so it took a while but it stopped).

FYI: Setting the NoConrolUpgrade=1 appears to be useless. The Kill bits for the OCX force VB6 to override the setting.

Answer (score -1):

First, yes, you probably answered your own question.

MS has never been good with 'side by side' installs, and even the "Side by Side" implementation they came up with was bone dead.  So my guess is that you are correct in assuming that two versions will cause problems.  But that is just a guess based on experience.

Moreover, and not so much an answer to your question, but I'm with you on the maintaining older vb - regardless of some moronic comments that vb5/6 won't work on 'new windows', it still does (as long as you don't use a microsoft installer).

Like you, I now have to face reality and deal with a new learning curve. (upgrading loads of 'old' stuff).  At least you have server 2012 running.  I'm just coming to terms with that mess.

In delving into new code, and trying as best I can to put away notions of the stupidity of the syntax,  I find I'm discovering new things that I like.  And some that simply confound logical reasoning.

Since stack is not a forum for discussion, as was pointed out last time I got blocked, if you want to compare notes on getting up to speed, you can reach me at gjr!rockley.net

I'm sure you can fig that out.

Either Way, Good luck with it.

Gary

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Gary. I'm hoping these changes will be the 'magic bullet' that slays all these crazy random errors. I will definitely post it here if it succeeds. I'm hoping this will at least convince the company owner to let me start working on a web based, .NET solution.

Comment: Bear in mind that any JIT solution, (.NET or C#, F#)  are easily compromised (from a code expsoure point of view) and nowhere near as secure as as C++ or even older VB with correct Sec employed.  Gary